# How can I verify that a specific cast is valid using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, static-code-analysis

Given two `ITypeSymbol`s (`a` and `b`), how does one check whether it is legal to explicitly cast from one into the other?  I'm trying to write a Code Analyzer that predicts whether an InvalidCastException is going to be thrown at runtime on a specific CastExpressionSyntax.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`SemanticModel.GetConversion(castNode)`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpExtensions.cs,670) and look at the properties of the returned `Conversion`.

For more examples of how to examine casts, see the [`IsUnnecessaryCast` method](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/Extensions/CastExpressionSyntaxExtensions.cs,275).